# Automatic Styling of directory listing in apache

Tags: html, css, apache

Good day, im working on styling apache directory listing. i have successfully added css styling to my current directory listing(using  the header.html, footer.html and autoindex.css) but my question is this, how can i configure my apache so that everytime i upload a new directory on my server, my css styling automatically works on it. thanks in advance

regards,
norbert

Comment: According to the mod_autoindex documentation you can set the server wide css file with the `IndexStyleSheet` directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you add

```
Options +Indexes
```

to a .htaccess file, Apache will generate an index file for the directory that the .htaccess file is in, as well as any subdirectories. If the other directories you want indexes generated for are not subdirectories, you will need another .htaccess file in each of them.

Comment: i have already done that to my .htaccess file and it still is not working.